# Mini displayport to HDMI adapter that does 4k at 60hz

Tags: hdmi, display-port, 4k

I just bought Sony X800D TV and it comes with 2 hdmi ports that do 4k at 60Hz and 1 HDMI port that does 4k at 30hz. I have 2015 Macbook Pro 15" with iris pro IGP. As you guys probably know, this macbook support just HDMI 1.4 and it only does 4k at 30hz. I want to output 4k at 60hz and my TV only has HDMI, so I cannot use display port or thunderbolt from my mac. I'm wondering if I could use mini displayport to HDMI adapter to output 4k 60hz. I tried one adapter from Wal-mart with 4k label, but my mac doesn't even recognize the TV is 4k capable anymore.

P.S : I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question. If it is not, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever looking for a solution to the similar problem, I went with [this club3d adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017BQ8I54). You will need to use SwitchResX software to force OSX to output 4k@60Hz. There are tons of online resources on how to create a custom resolution in SwitchResX, so I'm not going to post it here. Club3d is a bit more expensive than @NZKshatriya's suggestion. I would give it a try before buying Club3d.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to use the Thunderbolt port of your MacBook to output the signal. According to [everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.2-15-iris-only-mid-2015-retina-display-specs.html), your MacBook is definitely capable of outputting 4k@60Hz.

Now, you need a Mini Displayport to HDMI adapter, which does support 60Hz at 4k. I found [this one](http://a.co/10aOPzi), and a [customer's review](https://www.amazon.com/review/R20OPUIKBQ753K/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00S0BWR2K) verifies that it does work on his MacBook Pro 2015.

Also note, that you need a HDMI 2.0 capable cable as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:  [Vantec VLink CB-HD20MDP12](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232066&ignorebbr=1&cm_re=mini_displayport_to_HDMI_2.0-_-12-232-066-_-Product)

```
UHD resolution up to 4096 x 2160 at 60Hz, 8-bit color
Compliant to DisplayPort Specification 1.2
Compliant to HDMI Specification 2.0
HDCP 1.4 and HDCP 2.2 content protection
3D video up to 1080P@120Hz
Color format: support RGB up to 12 bpc; YCbCr 4:4:4/4:2:2/4:2:0 up to 12bpc
Audio input: support up to 8 channels of LPCM at 192kHz sample rate and 24-bit audio sample size, compressed audio and high bit rate
DisplayPort: support 1.1a/ 1.2a/1.3; 1/2/4 lanes at 1.62/2.7/5.4 Gbps
DisplayPort Spread Spectrum Clocking
Supports 4K NVidia GTX series and ATI Graphics
```

Comment: I went with Club3d adapter so I can't comment on this. But if it works, then obviously it's more affordable option.